# "org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject not found" after update from Intershop 7.7 to 7.9

Tags: intershop

I just updated a project from Intershop Commerce Management 7.7 to 7.9, everything went well, except I now get one compile error:

```
...\app_sf_responsive\javasource\com\intershop\application\responsive\internal\preview\call\CMSPageCallInterface.java:54: error: cannot access EObject
        for(Parameter p : PageletModelUtils.INSTANCE.getCallParameterDefinitions(app.getExtension(ApplicationBOPageletModelRepository.class), cepd))
                                                    ^
  class file for org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject not found
```

Did I miss some migration steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get this error because of missing compile dependencies. You need to insert following statements into the dependency closure of your build.gradle file:

dependencies 
{
   ...
   compile 'org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.common'
   compile 'org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore'
   ...
}

I hope that helps to succeed you migration tasks.